# xargs -0 produce new line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, xargs

I have the following files :

```
#ls
test  test2  test3  test4
```

now according to xargs -0 the input is trimmed based on null instead of whitespace, hence as there is no null in my input the 4 files should be printed in one echo command . The result is one echo command However there is a new line between each file :

```
#ls | xargs -0
test
test2
test3
test4
```

To be sure there is one command only :

```
 ls | xargs -0 -p
echo test
test2
test3
test4
 ?...n
```

why there is new line between each file ?

Comment: Yup. BTW, better practice to use `printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0`, so you're getting NUL-delimited input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `ls` prints to a TTY it formats the file names in columns, but when it's writing to a file, pipe, or other non-TTY it behaves like `ls -1` and prints one file name per line. You can check this by running `ls | cat` in place of `ls`.

With `ls | xargs -0`, the newlines are coming from `ls`, not from `xargs`. `xargs` is indeed reading a single string as you expect it to, but that string has newlines.

**See also:**

- [BashFAQ - Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 1):

You are not supplying a command to `xargs` which is unusual. The [default command `xargs` uses](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) when none is supplied is `/bin/echo`. `xargs` reads the output from `ls` and splits it into words; each word becomes a parameter for the command `xargs` executes. The `-0` option makes the null character the word delimiter used for the splitting. Because null does not appear in the output of `ls`, the entire output is considered one word and passed to `/bin/echo` as a single parameter, effectively resulting in the command line

```
/bin/echo 'test
test2
test3
test4'
```

That the output from `ls` contains newlines, on the other hand, is a property of `ls` when the putput is not a terminal, as John correctly explained.

Answer (score 0):

When xarging over files use `find` instead of `ls`!

```
$ find /my/path -print0 | xargs -0 -p
```

With `-print0` you can handle also files where space (0x20) is used in filename.